# qt_gui_main() found multiple plugins matching

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error in the subject prevents the rqt plugin from running.

```
$ pwd
/home/noodlerv/cws_viz
$ rospack find rqt_launch                                                                                                                                  
/home/noodlerv/cws_viz/src/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/rqt_launch
$ rospack find rqt_launchtree                                                                                                                               
/home/noodlerv/cws_viz/src/pschillinger/rqt_launchtree
$ rqt --standalone rqt_launch
qt_gui_main() found multiple plugins matching "rqt_launch"
rqt_launch.launch_plugin.LaunchPlugin
rqt_launchtree.launchtree_plugin.LaunchtreePlugin
$ rosversion qt_gui
0.2.32
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

The above example is using source but this happens also with installed binaries.

Since `rqt_launchtree` is introduced later than `rqt_launch`, I looked into rqt_launchtree to see if anything that `qt_gui` might reference to to lead into the raised error (e.g. exact string `rqt_launch`) but failed to find anything suspicious. Therefore I assume this error occurs because of the current spec of qt_gui.

Is there anyway to avoid this error without changing package name and anything that affects api and/or existing applications?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253315/qt_gui_main()-found-multiple-plugins-matching/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2017-01-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The string you pass to `--standalone` needs to uniquely identify one plugin. In this case you could achieve that by passing `rqt --standalone rqt_launch.` (note the trailing dot to make it unique). Obviously `rqt --standalone rqt_launchtree.launchtree_plugin.LaunchtreePlugin` would work too.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0